# PHP file not found?

Tags: php, macos, localhost

So I'm attempting to use `include`. Here's my `index.php`

```
<?php
include ("r.php");
?>
```

As you can see it simply includes `r.php`. And here's my `r.php`

```
<?php
echo "This is the included code";
?>
```

This is where the files are both located [image]

So when I run `index.php` I get

> PHP Warning: include(r.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in - on line 2 PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening 'r.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in - on line 2

I've also tried  `include "r.php";`, note the parentheses, but I'd still get the same error.
Any ideas?

Comment: are you running throught command line or web ? if it's command line.. make sure you put the absolute path or else php will use the path you are in while including files.

Comment: why did you tag with `localhost` if it is on the web?

Comment: Is the screenshot of the files from your local computer, or the remote web directory?

Comment: Wouldn't localhost technically be the web? Since its not command it has to be web? @celeriko

Comment: Local computer @larsAnders

Comment: Can you check your file name `r.php` has any white spaces ?

Comment: No white spaces on the file name and within the PHP. @KrishR

Comment: @colourity are the files you are trying to view hosted on a web server, i.e. you have to ftp or ssh to access them? then its on the web.  are the files you are trying to view on your own computer? then it is localhost

Comment: I'm running them on localhost. They're solely on my computer. @celeriko

Comment: Can you use the absolute path for `r.php` and see if that at least works?

Comment: Just tested an it works! Get an answer posted an I'll accept it. Thanks @steven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the absolute path for `r.php` and that should work

Comment: This ia a great answer but you should at least consider using a system variable like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to output the absolute path. This will help if you move the project elsewhere, it will automatically adjust to the new path.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to include the file relative to the current file:

```
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'r.php');
```

Also, make sure that the webserver has permission to view that file.

Edit: Use abolute path

Comment: I get this error `PHP Warning: include(//r.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in - on line 2 PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening '//r.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in - on line 2`

Comment: updated answer.. does the webserver has permission to read the file ?

Comment: Updated answer again.. use absolute path ?

Comment: Yet another error. `PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant DOCUMENT_ROOT - assumed 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' in - on line 2`....

Comment: my bad.. that was a typo.. use quote on `'DOCUMENT_ROOT'`

Answer (score 1):

Try finding your current working directory.  Then appending the source code path and then your file.  Keep in mind directory separators are different for different OS's

```
$ds = "\\"; // if your on a windows machine
include(getcwd().$ds.$sourceCodeDirPath.$ds."r.php");
```